# How do I alter appearance of Sign in with Apple button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here I have the Swift code for the SignInWithAppleButton. However I want to change its appearance like demonstrated here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple#) in the section that has the header "Creating a custom Sign in with Apple button"

How do I change this:

```
 SignInWithAppleButton { request in
                                        } onCompletion: { result in
                                        }
```

So it looks like this:

```
Button(action: {
                                            print("Apple Tapped")
                                        }) {
                                            Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                                                .font(.system(size: 70))
                                                .foregroundStyle(.white)

                                        }
```